# How to solve Invalid passcode MTA in the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to login in my Oracle Cloud Infrastructure. Then I put user and password, so I get a page asking 2-Step Verification. Until here ok, I go to Oracle Authenticator in my android app and get passcode, I put this one in the 2-Step Verification page but always receive "Invalid passcode".

The support tell me to login and change the url of 2-Step Verification page as below:

from

```
https://idcs-*******.identity.oraclecloud.com/
```

to

```
https://idcs-*******.identity.oraclecloud.com/ui/v1/myconsole?root=my-info&my-info=my_profile_security
```

But when a press enter, it always returns to page asking login and password.

How to solve this problem with 2-Step Verification?
Thanks

Comment: Please be sure that you are **logged in** before trying to access the 2-Step Verification page. If you're still being redirected, it could be due to a session timeout. In this case, try logging in again.

Comment: Talk to Oracle Cloud Support. This is not a programming problem and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm trying this right away. I log in and change the new URL and press enter... Then I'm redirected to log in again